# Theme: Find out styles hierarchy

Tags: codenameone

Hope you are doing fine overthere.

Is there a way to easily find out a theme styles hierarchy?  What derives from what?

Thanks for your help.

E

Comment: Do you mean programmatically, reading the CSS or opening the .res file?

Comment: I mean opening the .res since I know now from Shai's answer that it's not possible from within the compiled app.

Comment: Open the *.res with the Codename One Designer, click on the theme you are interested to, click on a UIID (i.e.: "DialogButton"), click on "Derive": you will see the UIID form which the current UIID is derived from (i.e.: "DialogButtonCommand"). Repeting the same step, for example I can see that, in my case, "DialogButtonCommand" derives from "Button".

Comment: Hello Francesco, thanks for answering.  I agree when the value is there however in some cases the "Override Attribute" is on which makes the dropdown disabled not showing anything.  That's where I am stuck.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with a case where it's disabled, can you give an example?
Notice that this won't show the hierarchy, it will just show the component you derived in your specific theme but it won't show if Button derived Label etc.

Comment: Hello Shai, here is a simple case: create a new project (theme=business, template=hello world), open the theme.res with the resource editor, go to the theme, select the style (UIID) "Label" and go to the tab Derive.  There, you'll see the "Override Attribute" is selected and the dropdown is disabled and empty.  Hence, I have no idea where "Label" gets its derived attributes.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suppose that, in the case you described, the "Label" of your theme derives its attributes from the "Label" of the native theme. You can inspect Android and iOS native themes downloading their res files and opening them: https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-skins/tree/master/Phones

Comment: Builtin types shouldn't be derived because that can lead to loops (child deriving parent which derives child). Even if they are derived this is an implementation detail which might change and does change between platforms (based on the native theme). You can't rely on any fields pre-existing value and need to explicitly define everything

Comment: Francesco, your comment is opening my mind to a new world of resources, I’m trying not to get confused. You’re telling me that the Label style in my resource actually takes its derived attributes from the targeted resource style at compile time, correct?
Shai, thanks.  I guess I misunderstood the type of hierarchy that was implemented in the business theme.  Tell me if I’m wrong, it’s actually as flat as possible, all the styles derives from the Default style, right?  I don’t know why I was originally convinced some styles derived from others.
Thanks both for you help.  Really appreciate.

Comment: @ebardet In the Codename One Designer, click on the "constants" tab. You will see several constants. One of them is "includeNativeBool" that is set to true and MUST be set to true. However, try to set it to false to see the difference: when it is false, your theme doesn't derive anything from the native theme. This will break the UI. Then set it to true again. The only case in which includeNativeBool MUST be false is when you have multiple themes used together in your project: only the basic theme must have includeNativeBool set to true, the others must have it set to false.

Comment: "Understanding Codename One Themes": https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html#theme-basics-section

Comment: Thanks, Francesco.

Answer (score 1):

No. The hierarchy of Codename One styles is static. The derive behavior is implemented during the load process only by using the style elements of the base as a starting point.

Once this is done the concept of inheritance if discarded and no longer applicable. So changes to the base style will no longer have an impact.